# Display multiple tables from nested object in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have an object like this:

```
myObject = {
'V-FR-TH1': [
  {
    version: '1.1',
    objectId: '001',
    modifiedNumbers: [
      { name: 'mod1', id: '0001m' },
      { name: 'mod2', id: '0002m' },
      { name: 'mod21', id: '00021m' },
    ],
  },
],
'N-DE-HG4': [
  {
    version: '1.3',
    objectId: '003',
    modifiedNumbers: [
      { name: 'mod3', id: '0003m' },
      { name: 'mod3', id: '0003m' },
    ],
  },
 ],
};
```

And a simple html just to display a table like this:
[image]

The main problem should be here when I try to iterate the inner object (nested modifiedNumbers array)

HTMl code:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of myObject | keyvalue: mySortingFunction">
  <div style="background-color:yellow">
    {{ item.key }}
  </div>
 <table>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>name</td>
    <tr *ngFor="let innerItem of item.value.modifiedNumbers">
      <td>{{ innerItem.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ innerItem.name }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
```

I really don't know how I can solve this , here is the sandbox link with my try:
[link here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tphvsq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

it contains the following error:

```
Property 'modifiedNumbers' does not exist on type '{ version: string; objectId: string; 
modifiedNumbers: { name: string; id: string; }[]; }[]'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the below answer is suitable for you.

**let innerItem of item.value[0].modifiedNumbers**

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of myObject | keyvalue: mySortingFunction">
  <div style="background-color:yellow">
    {{ item.key }}
  </div>
  <table>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>name</td>
    <tr *ngFor="let innerItem of item.value[0].modifiedNumbers ">
      <td>{{ innerItem.id}}</td>
      <td>{{ innerItem.name }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br />
</div>
```

Thank you.